# scoped pointers and reset

Tags: c++, boost, scoped-ptr

I am playing around with boost scoped pointers and I don't understand this behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{

    boost::scoped_ptr<int> p{new int{1}};
    std::cout << &p << '\n';
    p.reset(new int {2});
    std::cout << &p << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
0x7fff5fbff650
0x7fff5fbff650
```

Shouldn't the reset function change the address pointed by p?
this is the case if use a scoped array instead of a scoped pointer and print the address pointed by the first element in the code above.

Comment: thanks, just tried p.get() and indeed got different addresses.

Comment: remotely related: note that `operator&` could be overloaded to return what you expect (it is not) and for such cases there is `std::adressof`

Answer (score 7):

When you do

```
std::cout << &p << '\n';
```

you are getting the address of `p`, not what `p` points to.  To get that you need

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p.get()) << '\n';
```

---

The `static_cast<void*>()` is not really needed in this example as printing a pointer, other than a `char*`/`const char*` will give you its address but I added it to just be safe.

Comment: The `void*` cast is unnecessary in this example. It is only needed when dealing with `char*` pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've noted that in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You're taking the address of the `scoped_ptr` called `p`. There's only one of them!

If you'd printed `&*p` or `p.get()` instead (though prefer `(void*)p.get()` for sanity) then you'd be printing the address of *the thing it currently points to*.

This address will always change, because you create the second object (using `new`) slightly before the first one is destroyed, and objects cannot share addresses.

If you'd done a `.reset()` first, though, then you may or may not see this address changing, depending on what the innards of `new` did; objects don't *have* to have addresses unique to the lifetime of your program, as long as they don't share the address of another object that still exists! However, even then, in practice, to be honest, I'd be surprised if the second dynamically-allocated `int` wound up at the same address as the first.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing address of object p with is a boost::scoped_ptr.
You should use p.get() to get address of handle object;